# How do I change my 1080p external monitor from portrait to landscape on an Eee PC 1000H?

Tags: display, resolution, external-monitor, eeepc

Hi I have an EeePC 1000H netbook with a Samsung T22A350 1080p 22" external monitor.

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and I mainly use the external display but when I select 1080 from the dropdown list, my only options are for a rotated portrait.

My neck's non too supple, so tilting my head for extended periods is not really viable. :-)

Any ideas on making ubuntu display 1080 normal landscape?

It must be possible as using a gparted boot cd does it perfectly.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, Here was my fix:
I went to system > Display like you, and I clicked the slider for my laptop to the off position. Then I could place my monitor at full

Answer (score 0):

The video chipset on some laptops (particularly, netbooks with Intel N10 video) can only drive a total of 2048x2048 pixels, so the 1024 from internal display plus the 1920 from the external "overflow" that horizontally. One thing you could try is arranging the monitors one on top of each other, this will allow you to use full resolution (hopefully).

Note that this limitation comes from those chipsets' inability to use a 3D texture larger than 2048x2048. So the other possible workaround is to use the Unity2D session, which doesn't use 3D textures and won't suffer from this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

What did the trick for me was:

1. Turn laptop screen off
2. Slide external monitor to the left of the laptop screen (in the top display that shows the two screens).

   Then the monitor got positioned in landscape mode again, also in higher resolutions.

Hope it helps.